Cannot use import statement outside a module when connecting to local postgres database
Currently learning back-end development via Codecademy and I have tried to follow the example in the following https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure to connect my API/Routes to my local database instance and have used the suggested db/index.js
import pg from 'pg'
const { Pool } = pg

const pool = new Pool()

export const query = (text, params, callback) =\> {
return pool.query(text, params, callback)
}

and then the routes/user.js file as given
    // notice here I'm requiring my database adapter file
    // and not requiring node-postgres directly
    import \* as db from '../db/index.js'
    
    app.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) =\> {
    const result = await db.query('SELECT \* FROM users WHERE id = $1', \[req.params.id\])
    res.send(result.rows\[0\])
    })


// ... many other routes in this file

However when I try to run/debug the application I get the following error
Currently learning back-end development via Codecademy and I have tried to follow the example in the following https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure to connect my API/Routes to my local database instance and have used the suggested db/index.js
import pg from 'pg'
const { Pool } = pg

const pool = new Pool()

export const query = (text, params, callback) => {
return pool.query(text, params, callback)
}

and then the routes/user.js file as given
    // notice here I'm requiring my database adapter file
    // and not requiring node-postgres directly
    import \* as db from '../db/index.js'
    
    app.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) =\> {
    const result = await db.query('SELECT \* FROM users WHERE id = $1', \[req.params.id\])
    res.send(result.rows\[0\])
    })

// ... many other routes in this file

However when I try to run/debug the application I get the following error
import \* as db from '../db/index.mjs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:128:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:20)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1332:27)
at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (D:\\Visual Studio Code\\Projects\\sweepstake\\app.js:4:21)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)

Node.js v20.12.2
I am sure I am missing some code to define the connection but am not sure.
Any help would be appreciated.
Waiting on reply from the source of the example code.
changing the import to a require statement
using a variable name rather than *

please share you package.json file

// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}

I think you need to put this code in package.json. so that you can import .js, .mjs file in any file.
Try this code. If you have any problem,  feel free to reach out to me.

I did find other questions with your suggested solution which unfortunately did not solve my problem. Perhaps I need to get a better understand of the pg (postgress) module and how to connect to my local database instance and get that file working so I know what is going on.
Thanks for your help
